# What will you use to memorized data in react native?

Tags: react-native, caching, asyncstorage

I'm really new to react native, and I'm building an application using the YouTube api, and in order to avoid blocking requests and also to improve performance, I want to save the request, meaning that if the user searched for the same thing twice the second time, it will not refer to the YouTube api,
I understood that **there is AsyncStorage that is equivalent to local storage, is it better to use it?**

I look forward to caching and saving unnecessary requests from the YouTube api